# How To get start date and end date of a current Quarter..?

Tags: java

As example If i got the month of August 2016 then i should get the start date as 01 Jul 2016 and end date as 30 September 2016(as this comes under 3rd quarter of this year). 
Can anybody explain a logic for this.?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? I also recommend looking into [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you are new at SO

Comment: There is no such method that given any date, it gives you back the start and end date of the quarter. You need to code it by yourself. Think about modulo operations and adding/subtracting days / months from the given date

Comment: Sorry for not explaining properly but as i mentioned above if input i give Aug as input i should get the first date of the quarter means first date of month  July and last date as last date of month Sept.

Comment: i don't want to give date as input  i want to give a month value or month name as input.. #Josep Prat

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting here?  Are you hoping someone will write the code for you?  It seems to me that you already understand the mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void printStartEndQuarter(int year, int month) {
    double thisMonth = (double)month;
    String quarter = thisMonth/3 <= 1 ? "Quarter 1" : thisMonth/3 <= 2 ? "Quarter 2" : thisMonth/3 <= 3 ? "Quarter 3" : "Quarter 4";
    if (month % 3 == 2) {
        month = month - 1;
    }

    else if (month % 3 == 0) {
        month = month - 2;
    }
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
    Month endMonth = start.getMonth().plus(2);

    LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(year, endMonth, endMonth.length(start.isLeapYear()));

    System.out.println("Start Date====" + start);
    System.out.println("End Date====" + end);
    System.out.println("quarter====" + quarter);

}
```

Hope this will help some one and it will work for any test case.Thank You @fabin.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Month` and `LocalDate`'s methods to get those dates:

```
public static void printStartEndQuarter(int year, Month month) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(year, month.firstMonthOfQuarter(), 1);

    Month endMonth = start.getMonth().plus(2);

    LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(year, endMonth, endMonth.length(start.isLeapYear()));

    System.out.println(start);
    System.out.println(end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it you do not understand? 3rd quarter of an year includes the months July, August and September, so start date of the quarter is the 1st day in July and end date is the last day of September. If you have February or March for example the start date will be 01 Jan 2016 and end date will be 31 Mar 2016. It is that simple.

Comment: Sorry sir but i can't find the logic and i will give the input as a month value like 01 for January and 02 for February or a month name like February or April.